# Node.js RESTful api. Response after post issue

Tags: javascript, node.js

learning Node.js and trying to create rest api. 
Now have this kind of services:

```
this.get = function(res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
        con.query('select * from todo_list', function(err, result) {
            con.release();
            res.send(result);
        });
    });
};

this.create = function(todo, res) {
    connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
        con.query('insert into todo_list set ?', todo, function(err, result) {
            con.release();
            if (err) {
                res.send({
                    status: 1,
                    message: "Todo creation failed"
                });
            } else {
                res.send({
                    status: 0,
                    message: "Todo created successfully"
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Question: how to return json on succesfull creation, for example:

```
{status: 0, message: ... , todos: [{id:1, name: 'Todo', date:...},{id:2, name: 'Todo', date:...}]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [res.json()](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.json):

```
res.json({status: 0, message: "Todo created successfully"});
```

In order to include the todo items in the response, you'll have to make another database call. Instead of duplicating the code for getting all todo items, you might want to create a separate function for obtaining the todo items without responding to the client.

```
this.getAllItems = function(callback) {
  connection.acquire(function(err, con) {
    con.query('select * from todo_list', function(err, result) {
      con.release();
      callback(result);
    });
  });
}

this.get = function (res) {
  this.getAllItems(function(result) {
    res.json(result);
  });
};

this.create = function (todo, res) {
  var self = this;
  connection.acquire(function(err, con){
    con.query('insert into todo_list set ?', todo, function(err, result){
      con.release();
      if(err) {
        res.json({status: 1, message: "Todo creation failed"});
      } else {
        self.getAllItems(function(items) {
          res.json({
            status: 0, 
            message: "Todo created successfully",
            todos: items
          });
        });
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Don't forget to add error handling, though. =)

Also, check out promises ([Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird), for example) to avoid callback hell.

Comment: But i need to add all saved items to that json also.

Comment: In that case you probably need to make a `SELECT` database request after successful insert. Which database library are you using?

Comment: node-mysql.
Oh, so no other way, just on success do a call to db again and then return response?

Comment: I'm afraid so. You insert a single row, right? Then you should be able to get the id of the inserted row with `result.insertId`.

Comment: Or if you want to return all todo items instead of just the inserted one, just go with `SELECT * FROM todo_list`.

Comment: Ok. My plan is to insert new row and as result return all saved items, to update list in UI. 
Strange that in create service i can't call this.get(); Getting undefined...

Comment: Than from UI you can resolve: Make a `POST` request to create and than o success you can make a `GET` to you endpoint and update your view with the todos result